# Jetbrains Datagrip cannot connect sql server without specify database

Tags: datagrip

i try to use Datagrip as my primary sql server query tools, bit i meet a problem that i can not move forward.

When i setup the project data source, i have to choose a Database, otherwise it will goto the default tempdb, how i can work like sql server management studio, that i can see all database list.

i have tried both jTds and Microsoft drivers, both not works.

or can i choose multi-database? i do not want to create one data source for one database.

if i connect to mysql, it works like expected.

tks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to connect without specifying the database. Just leave this field blank. After entering other settings (host, port, user, password), go to [Schemas](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2020.1/data-sources-and-drivers-dialog.html#schemasAndTablesTab) tab in Data Source properties and select all the Databases and schemas you want to work with. Then invoke **Synchronize** action for this Data Source in [Database tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/datagrip/2020.1/database-tool-window.html).

Answer (score 1):

DataGrip 2016.2 EAP claims to have support for showing multiple databases. See https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/ and find for "Database View".  Unfortunately, as of the date I'm writing this, it doesn't seem to work at all.

Unfortunately, Andrey's suggestion did not work for me.

Comment: works just fine. ensure when selecting microsoft SQL driver that you have not specified a database in the advanced tab and when making a connection, do not specify any database. if connection succeeds, simply click on more schemas in the database browser and choose the database you wish to connect to.